# DataTables: How do I add an empty row with a title?

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

I'm using this package https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables with Laravel 5.4 and trying to create a table that displays an empty row with the date like the image below. I can't figure out how to do this.
I don't have much code.

```
Datatables::of($results)
->editColumn("date", function($record) use(&$dates){
    return (new Carbon($record->date))->toDateString();
})
->make(true);
```

Is what i'm trying to do possible?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you are looking for row grouping : https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/examples/initialisation/endRender.html

Comment: @Md.SukelAli thanks this is what I needed

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Datatables::of($results)
->addColumn("date", function($record) use(&$dates){
$date = (new Carbon($record->date))->toDateString();
    return $date;
})
->make(true);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it